# Count occurence of character in files

Tags: linux, file, command-line, grep, wc

I want to count all `$` characters in each file in a directory with several subdirectories.
My goal is to count all variables in a PHP project. The files have the suffix `.php`.

I tried

```
grep -r '$' . | wc -c
grep -r '$' . | wc -l
```

and a lot of other stuff but all returned a number that can not match. In my example file are only four `$`.
So I hope someone can help me.

**EDIT**

My example file

```
<?php
class MyClass extends Controller {

$a;$a;
$a;$a;
$a;
$a;
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question - directories don't contain characters - files do. Do you wish to count `$`s in a set of files in some directory?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Count occurrences of a specific character in the file? Or filenames in the directory? Your title says one thing, and your command say something else.

Comment: I tried to add more details to the question. But I wish to count $s ind a set of files in some direcotroy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To recursively count the number of `$` characters in a set of files in a directory you could do:

```
fgrep -Rho '$' some_dir | wc -l
```

To include only files of extension `.php` in the recursion you could instead use:

```
fgrep -Rho --include='*.php' '$' some_dir | wc -l
```

The `-R` is for recursively traversing the files in `some_dir` and the `-o` is for matching part of the each line searched. The set of files are restricted to the pattern `*.php` and file names are not included in the output with `-h`, which may otherwise have caused false positives.

Comment: I used `grep -oR "\$" * | wc -l` but fgrep is the way to go. +1

Comment: And how can I say that it only should include php files? sorry didn't saw your edit

Comment: Is there a way to consider two $ signs in a row?

Comment: @EvilKarter Yes, see update again. The `-h` option should be used here.

Answer (score 1):

For counting variables in a PHP project you can use the `variable regex` defined [here](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php).

So, the next will grep all variables for each file:

```
cd ~/my/php/project
grep -Pro '\$[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*' .

-P - use perlish regex
-r - recursive
-o - each match on separate line
```

will produce something like:

```
./elFinderVolumeLocalFileSystem.class.php:$path
./elFinderVolumeLocalFileSystem.class.php:$path
./elFinderVolumeMySQL.class.php:$driverId
./elFinderVolumeMySQL.class.php:$db
./elFinderVolumeMySQL.class.php:$tbf
```

You want count them, so you can use:

```
$ grep -Proc '\$[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*' .
```

and will get the `count of variables in each file`, like:

```
./connector.minimal.php:9
./connector.php:9
./elFinder.class.php:437
./elFinderConnector.class.php:46
./elFinderVolumeDriver.class.php:1343
./elFinderVolumeFTP.class.php:577
./elFinderVolumeFTPIIS.class.php:63
./elFinderVolumeLocalFileSystem.class.php:279
./elFinderVolumeMySQL.class.php:335
./mime.types:0
./MySQLStorage.sql:0
```

When want count `by file and by variable`, you can use:

```
$ grep -Pro '\$[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*' . | sort | uniq -c
```

for getting result like:

```
  17 ./elFinderVolumeLocalFileSystem.class.php:$target
   8 ./elFinderVolumeLocalFileSystem.class.php:$targetDir
   3 ./elFinderVolumeLocalFileSystem.class.php:$test
  97 ./elFinderVolumeLocalFileSystem.class.php:$this
   1 ./elFinderVolumeLocalFileSystem.class.php:$write
   6 ./elFinderVolumeMySQL.class.php:$arc
   3 ./elFinderVolumeMySQL.class.php:$bg
  10 ./elFinderVolumeMySQL.class.php:$content
   1 ./elFinderVolumeMySQL.class.php:$crop
```

where you can see, than the variable `$write` is used only once, so (maybe) it is useless.

You can also count `per variable per whole project`

```
$ grep -Proh '\$[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*' . | sort | uniq -c
```

and will get something like:

```
  13 $tree
   1 $treeDeep
   3 $trg
   3 $trgfp
  10 $ts
   6 $tstat
  35 $type
```

where you can see, than the `$treeDeep` is used only once in a whole project, so it is sure useless.

You can achieve many other combinations with different `grep`, `sort` and `uniq` commands..